# Java - NoClassDefFoundError XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I creating CSV to XLSX app - [My first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286292/netbeans-org-apache-poi-cannot-access-date1904support?noredirect=1#comment99185735_56286292)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
        at com.test.csv2xlsx.Csv2Xlsx.<init>(Csv2Xlsx.java:35)
        at com.test.csv2xlsx.Csv2Xlsx.main(Csv2Xlsx.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

I read all the articles about this error, but I already had all dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Now I am not sure where is the problem

[image]

Comment: How are you executing? From the command-line? Are all the dependencies on your classpath?

Comment: Hi, yes from MS Windows CMD, is it possible in NetBeans include all dependencies into jar file?

Comment: Don't know what Netbeans offers out of the box, but the term to google for would be uberjar or fat jar. I think the maven shade plugin is currently the most used to build a jar with dependencies.

Comment: This article gives a good overview of your options: https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue. Your project's dependencies are not included in the jar you execute, leading to `NoClassDefFoundError`.

To fix add this to the `plugins` section of your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>
                            com.mypackage.Main
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then execute `mvn clean package` and when finished inside target directory you will find an executable `jar_name-jar-with-dependencies.jar` which contains all the required dependencies.

Finally simply `run java -jar jar_name-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

Comment: Hi, I also find now this solution, now it works fine thank you a lot for help